# How to highlight in rich.prompt.Prompt

Tags: python, highlight, rich

I have this highlighter

```
from rich.console import Console
import rich.prompt
from rich.highlighter import RegexHighlighter
from rich.theme import Theme


class Highlighter(RegexHighlighter):
    base_style = "help."
    highlights = [r"(?P<cmd>!help\b)", r"(?P<cmd2>\'|\"[\w]+\"|\')"]

theme = Theme({"help.cmd": "bold magenta", "help.cmd2": "bold green"})
console = Console(highlighter=Highlighter(), theme=theme)
```

If I do something like `console.print()` it gives the custom highlighting but it dosen't give custom highlighting for `rich.prompt.Prompt.ask()`

```
prompt = rich.prompt.Prompt(console=console)
text = prompt.ask("\'Enter text\'\n")
console.print(text)
```

[image]

How can I get the highlighter for `rich.prompt.Prompt.ask()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting the text you enter to be highlighted as you type?

Rich doesn't have that capability. You might want to look in to prompt_toolkit for that.